# Using Python to select records by date field

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, error-000358, datetime

I am trying to write a python script to select records created within the past 7 hours (date field - database time) using a where-clause within arcpy. The table is ArcSDE database (Microsoft SQL Server).

I've written a script that calculates the time 7 hours prior to the current time. Then I want to use the "report_time" variable to select the relevant records in a table view but I'm getting an invalid expression error. I've tried to reformat the SQL statement in every way I could think of and still get the invalid expression error (I've kept them in my script and commented them out for reference).

```
-- Get start and end times for report

start_time= datetime.timedelta(hours = 7)
end_time = datetime.datetime.now()

report_time = end_time-start_time #this is the time that gets used to filter records

-- find all records that are later than or = to report_time

SQL = "created_date >= " + report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print SQL

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(ViewTable,"NEW_SELECTION", SQL)

-- SQL = "created_date >= " + str(report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

-- SQL = '"created_date"<='+ report_time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

-- SQL = '"created_date"<='+ report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

-- SQL = "'created_date'<= "+ report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

-- SQL = '"created_date"<='+ report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') - ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression

-- SQL = "'created_date'<= "+ report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') - ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression

-- SQL = "'created_date'<= "+ str(report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))

-- SQL = '"created_date"<='+ str(report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))

--SQL = '"created_date"<= report_time.strftime'('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

--SQL = '"created_date" <= report_time' #this returns an expression error

--SQL = "'created_date' <= report_time" #also tried this - expression error

--SQL = 'created_date'<= report_time # returns error: TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
```

Comment: before trying to calculate the difference and pass that as your SQL, have you tried your `created_date >= somestaticdate` and checking that part works?

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: Date formatting is not at all standardized across databases.  Please **edit the question** to specify the data source format on which this query would be executed.

Comment: does the time formatting part - `report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` resolve? you didn't include the modules you imported in the script. are you using  `from time import strftime`?

Comment: @Midavalo - what you're asking is what I'm trying to test and it fails. It works in python shell but not as part of arcpy.

Comment: "ArcSDE database" does not come close to describing the data source -- each RDBMS has a *different* timestamp format; we need to know *which* RDBMS is in use to help

Comment: @Vince - thank you, I added that info to the original question. Its an ArcSDE Enterprise database - SQL backed. Using the select by attribute tool in arcpy

Comment: "SQL" is a language, used by all databases.  Do you mean "Microsoft SQL-Server"?

Comment: @Vince - my apologies - yes. Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: To guarantee that you're formatting your times the same way as the database, in ArcMap open the select by attributes tool for your table, select the date field, and then view what's actually in the database by clicking on the "get all values" or whatever it's called. Pattern your date/time formatting in your script to match. Note that this will probably look different than what you see in the attribute table

Comment: @rralbritton - I didn't see anywhere in your code that said anything like `SQL = "created_date >= '2016-02-06 05:00:00'"` which is why I asked if that worked

Comment: @Tom - thank you for the suggestion. I did that using this expression: #SQL = "'created_date'<= "+ report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') so that the date formats matched and still got the same "invalid expression" error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947436/datetime-in-where-clause

Comment: Then it looks like you just need single quotes around the time and not around the field name.

Comment: @Vince - that would work if I was scripting in SQL but I'm not. I'm writing the script in python using an arcpy module that requires a where clause. This is being written to build a geoprocessing tool

Comment: @Tom - I'm not clear on what you're suggesting. Since the table is an SDE table ESRI standards require quotes around the field name being queried against (http://support.esri.com/cN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40355). I've tried treating the time like a string, and the expression still failed

Comment: @Tom while using python with arcpy you need to include quotes around field names. That is how ArcGIS understands that it is a field. Unless you have a variable that stored it. like x="created_date"

Comment: It is important to understand that ArcGIS is ***NOT*** executing the query -- The database is. You must format the `WHERE` clause **as it will be used by the database**.

Comment: @rralbritton I don't think that link means what you think it means.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether `ArcSDE` or `MicrosoftSQL` is used to read  the data. For people who is not using SQL server "the without quotes" solution may not work.

Answer (score 4):

So I figured it out - @Yanes was close but instead of three sets of double quotes, it needed to be double-single-double. So the following script works:

```
-- Turn ReportsTable into a View Table

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(ReportsTable, ViewTable)

-- Get start and end times for report

start_time= datetime.timedelta(hours = 24)

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()

report_time = end_time-start_time #this is the time that gets used to filter records

-- find all records that are later than or = to report_time

SQL = "created_date >="+ "'"+report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+"'"

print SQL

-- select records within the specified time range using arcpy
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(ViewTable,"NEW_SELECTION", SQL)
```

Comment: `SQL = "created_date >= '{}'".format(report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: This is why you should never concatenate strings with +.

Comment: great! however check with `arcpy.GetCount_management('ViewTable')` , to see if you've correctly selected records. or add `print arcpy.GetMessages()` after your select by attribute line. To check what it did. Not that I am saying it doesn't work, just wondering because I didn't think specifying field without quotations worked. Also please accept your answer so that people could see the Q has an accepted answer.

Comment: @yanes I believe a field in a SQL feature class is selected without quotes eg `fieldname = 'value'`.  a field in a file geodatabase requires square brackets `[fieldname] = 'value'` and shapefile requires double-quotes `"fieldname" = 'value'`

Comment: To use the simple ArcGIS SQL syntax. It is `""" "fieldname" = 'value' """` Where the triple quotations means you get to use the simple SQL structure ArcGIS uses.  In ArcGIS desktop, there are 2 options  `[fieldname] = 'value'` for VB and `!fieldname! = 'value'` for Python. Where of course you don't put any quotations in cases where the value is integer or float.  [example](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/specifying-a-query.htm). There was also another weirder way of  escaping the SQL format with staggered backslashes instead of the triple quotes.

Comment: Interesting, because your solution is exactly what I said earlier: "Then it looks like you just need single quotes around the time and not around the field name." Maybe it wasn't clear that I was referring to quotes within the SQL query itself.

Comment: Ah! moment here! :) I've learned a number of SQL alternatives thank you!

Comment: @yanes - good point on using the GetCount tool - I did use that to check the records being selected, I just didn't include that info here - but its useful advice for anyone in the same/similar situation

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your Where statement with three double quotations so that Arcpy understands it as an expression for your select function not a standalone SQL task - I may be wrong on the reasoning, I will check.

```
SQL = """ "created_date" >= '{}'""".format(report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(ViewTable,"NEW_SELECTION", SQL)
```

Also why do you have two operands in the SQL?

Comment: Yanes - thanks for the reply but its still doesn't work - By adding all of the quotes its reading the entire SQL as a string which is incorrect: 

SQL = """ "created_date >= " report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')""" returns this as the SQL statement:

"created_date >= " report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').

Also - someone asked why I had a double operand - that was just a mistake type. Sorry I should have proofed that better

Comment: Help me understand the SQL isn't it supposed to be a simple statement where: you are looking at a field named `"Created_date"` and selecting all the records that are later or on the date specified by your variable `report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`. In that case this statement should work. 2 things. 1. please confirm `created_date` is your field, 2. confirm that the variable `report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` doesn't give you error, when run on its own.

Comment: Also Vince's comment under the original post is valid, check in a GIS software how exactly the time/date is formatted in your table your `report_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` need to reproduce the exact format. You can also use searchcursor to print your records out in python and see the format.

Comment: Also you keep putting the operand with in the field name quotation, that is not what is supposed to happen it should be  `"created_date" >=` not `"created_date >= "`. The idea is to have something as simple as`""" "a" >= b """`. The triple quotations are needed for python to resolve it appropriately. The basic SQL should be the form of `"a" >= b` with `a` in double quotation as it is a field name `the operand` with no quotation and  `b` as it is, b/c its a variable. But make sure that `b` resolves into something like '2016-02-06 05:00:00' as @Midavalo's example.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I figured it out. Please see my post below

Comment: @rralbritton, cool, I edited my answer for an arcpy-ish alternative.

Comment: @yanes I think you still need the single quotes `""" "created_date" >= '{}'""".format(report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` - it fails for me without them, but works with them (and including the triple quotes).  But nice, I didn't know about the triple quotes.  Both `""" "created_date" >= '{}'""".format(report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` and `"created_date >= '{}'".format(report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` worked for me in this instance, but I suppose there are times you'd use one over the other

Comment: @Midavalo, thanks! for the correction, it was a mistake! I have edited it now. I didn't know about the second option, good to know. It looks less of a coloring book without the triple double quotes :). I am not sure if I remember correctly - there is an unimaginative alternative that goes as - `/"created_date >= '{}'/".format(report_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`